# Is there any way for me to be able to get my surround back to my G930 Headset?

Tags: sound, logitech

I have a Logitech G930 headset. I recently decided to go 100% full on ubuntu, and i am loving it so far. However, this is sadly the only thing i've hit a brick wall with. I have googled ways to find drivers for the logitech G930 or get Logitech gaming software to work.

Normally this would not be a issue, but when you have surround turned off on the logitech G930 it sounds plastic and horrible. Is there ANY way to get this to work?

Best regards, Marco.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at the moment, the drivers only support analog and digital stereo, as you can [see here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2117154).